# How do I update column of large object in nativequery from input string

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with hibernate,JPA, and PostgreSql.I want to update database of large object column,.I have defining my long text in entity as @Lob

```
@Lob
@Column(name="comment", columnDefinition = "Text")
private String comment;
```

whenever I write a query

```
@Query(value = "update table set comment = (:comment) where id =(:id)", nativeQuery=true)
void updateComment(@param('comment')String comment, @param('id') Long id);
```

updating column with string instead of converting of large object.

```
id | comment
------------------
1  |  hello
```

instead of

```
id | comment
------------------
1  |  270038051
```

My question is how to write update native query to replace the large object from input String?

Answer (score 0):

Use native query as below format.

UPDATE table_name SET column_name = lo_get(cast(column_name as bigint))

Comment: Thanks for response, solution you had suggested is not working as expected. It throwing invalid input syntax for integer:"hello".

Answer (score 0):

I modified query as below and it works well.

```
Update table set comment = lo_from_bytea(0, convert_to('hello', 'UTF8')) where id=1
```

Hurry!!